# CMake does not include/embed linked library

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, cmake

I have a CMake list file that builds a c++ library that I have, including 5 third party c++ libraries, which are also built with cmake. This project builds an android .aar library and an iOS framework.

While android works flawlessly, I find problem after problem with iOS. I manage to build a .framework file, but it does NOT include the third party libraries (that get built correctly), so to be able to use the .framework I end up needing to manually add the third party libraries manually to my App project.

How can I tell CMake that the libraries must be included/embedded/shipped with the .framework file?

What I currently have is:

```
...

# libpng
include_directories(${ROOT}/thirdparties/libpng)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparties/libpng)
set(PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR ${ROOT}/thirdparties/libpng)
set(PNG_LIBRARY png16_static)
set(PNG_SHARED OFF)
set(PNG_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "skip tests for libpng")
add_subdirectory(${ROOT}/thirdparties/libpng)


... (almost the same for all third party libraries)


if( IOS )
    add_library(myLibrary STATIC ${SOURCES} ${SOURCES_JNI} ${SOURCES_MYSQL} ${PUBLIC_HEADER} ${RESOURCES})
else()
    add_library(myLibrary SHARED ${SOURCES} ${SOURCES_JNI} ${SOURCES_MYSQL} ${PUBLIC_HEADER} ${RESOURCES})
endif()


target_link_libraries(myLibrary
        hpdfs
        png16_static
        ${mysqlcppconn}
        zlibstatic
        ${CRYPTO_LIBRARY}
        ${PTHREAD}
)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is your expectation that the static libs are embedded in your framework?

Comment: @MobileBen yes, that is what I want to obtain at the end!

Comment: A few other dumb questions on my end. 1. Is the snippet above what you are using in the "application" that uses the framework? 2. Why don't you use static lib versus framework for iOS? Does the application itself depend on any of the libs you want to include? 3. In your list above, which ones should myLibrary embed? FWIW, I'm asking because in my setup I actually use static libs v. frameworks and I opt for having the application specifically link in the libs. I can go through the reasoning, but want to better understand your use case.